# Images won't show up on all pages of mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having an issue with my MVC website project. The images I am using on my website will only show up when I call that specific page for example when I use

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

The images will only show up on my index page. If I click on one of the links to my other pages the images will not show up. Lets say I change action=**Index** to action=**List**. Now only the images in `List` will show up and no images will show up in `Index`. Same thing goes for my css stylesheet.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your issue, pls point it out. Thanks for your response in advance

Answer (score 0):

The routing rule is the default rule of MVC, so I don't know how you put your images files and how you use them, here's code snippet in my test, and in the default `home/index` page and the `home/edit` page, I both add 2 png files which stored in `wwwroot/img` folder. And both the images displayed well.

```
@*using imgs in index page*@
<img src="~/img/11.png">
<img src="~/img/22.png">
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Edit">jump to edit page</a>

@*using imgs in edit page*@
<img src="~/img/11.png">
<img src="~/img/22.png">
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
```

[image]
[image]